# Remove a symbol and number from a file name VB

Tags: vb.net, string

I am reading in a few file names that have the same basic title but have `#n` at the end, where `n` is some number. For example, `Sony#1`, `Salmon#2`, `Cats#3`, etc. I want to strip the `#n` from the end of the file name, so `Sony#1` would become `Sony` and so on. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you clarify your question, what do you want to compare with what?

Comment: It will be compared with a variable that is exactly the same as the name less the number.  If imgfile ((MINUS)#1 or #2 ...#10) = Variable

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim fileName as String = "Sony#1"
Dim fileKeyword as String = Split(fileName, "#")(0) ' Sony
```

Comment: Please provide some more detail.

Comment: @MikeStockdale please provide some more detail in your comment. What more do you want? This splits a string by '#' and returns the first token.

Comment: @dkurbz I agree, your answer is accurate and concise.

Answer (score 1):

If the number is always preceded by `#` then you can try this:

```
Dim str As String '= "Name#3"
Dim sCat As String = str.Substring(0, str.LastIndexOf("#"c))
```

Comment: I was curious about performance, and tested this against Split(), and found this solution to be about 10 times faster than the Split() option. While I would have used Split() in the past, I need to remember this method. Thanks